How do I move the boxplot and datapoints, together, a bit to the left?
I am visualising the data for the bill depth for these birds for 1976 and 1978. I want a single figure showing boxplot + datapoints, next to the half violin plot, for each year.
I have managed to get this (see image), but I just need to move the boxplot+datapoints a little bit to the left so that they are not overlapping with the half-violin plots.
Any ideas on how to do this so that I can have both boxplots and half-violin side-by-side, with the datapoints overlaid on the boxplots?
Here is my code:
library(Sleuth3) #contains the data
library(ggplot2) 

finch_data <- (case0201) #saves the data from the Sleuth3 package

exploratory_plot <- ggplot(
  data = finch_data,
  aes(x = factor(Year), y = Depth, fill = factor(Year))) +
  geom_violinhalf() +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.3, outlier.shape = NA) +  
  geom_jitter(width = 0.2, alpha = 0.3) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = year_colours, guide = "none") +
  labs(x = "Year", y = "Bill depth (mm)") +
  theme_bw()

exploratory_plot

